# Defining a variable data type at run-time in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that contains a parameter that allows the user to pick which fields and which order the fields will be displayed on the report.  The only issue I am running into is that the data types can be string, number, or date and I cannot figure out how to check the data type (I convert everything to a string at first) and then change the value to the correct data type.  I would imagine the formula would look something like:

```
numbervar counter;
shared stringvar Array FieldVal;
counter := count({?Fields}); 

if counter >= 5 then

if NumericText(FieldVal[5]) then tonumber(FieldVal[5]) else
if isdate(FieldVal[5]) then CDate(FieldVal[5]) else
FieldVal[5]
```

The problem is I get an error message "A date is required here." or "A number is required here."

if counter >= 5 then
(if NumericText(FieldVal[5]) and not(isdate(FieldVal[5])) then val(FieldVal[5]));

if counter >= 5 then

(if Not(NumericText(FieldVal[5]) and isdate(FieldVal[5])) then
FieldVal[5]);

if counter >= 5 then
(if isdate(FieldVal[5]) and not(numerictext(FieldVal[5])) then CDate(FieldVal[5]));

returns a Date data type

if counter >= 5 then

(if Not(NumericText(FieldVal[5]) and isdate(FieldVal[5])) then
FieldVal[5]);

if counter >= 5 then
(if isdate(FieldVal[5]) and not(numerictext(FieldVal[5])) then CDate(FieldVal[5]));

if counter >= 5 then
(if NumericText(FieldVal[5]) and not(isdate(FieldVal[5])) then val(FieldVal[5]));

Returns a number data type, and this is what ends up showing on the report no matter what the actual data type is.

I have also tried the following and receive the equivalent of a data type mismatch:

```
numbervar counter;
Shared StringVar Array FieldVal;
Shared NumberVar Array FieldValNbr;
Shared DateVar Array FieldValDte;
StringVar DType := '';
StringVar StrValue := FieldVal[5];
NumberVar NbrValue := FieldValNbr[5];
DateVar DteValue := FieldValDte[5];

counter := count({?Fields}); 

if counter >= 5 then
if StrValue <> '' then DType := 'String';
if NbrValue <> 0 then DType := 'Number';
if StrValue <> '' and NbrValue <> 0 then DType := 'Date';

Select DType
case 'String' : StrValue 
Case 'Number' : NbrValue
Case 'Date' : DteValue;
```

[Data returned. The first Pay Rate as defined in the formula returns a string, and the second Pay Rate is what it should be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS54P.png)

```
Shared numbervar counter;
shared stringvar Array FieldVal;

if counter >= 5 then
(
if NumericText(FieldVal[5]) then tonumber(FieldVal[5])
);

if counter >= 5 then
(
if isdate(FieldVal[5]) then CDate(FieldVal[5])
);

if counter >= 5 then
(
if Not(NumericText(FieldVal[5]) and isdate(FieldVal[5])) then
FieldVal[5]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in that way you wrote the code, because in a single `if or if else` statement there can't be different datatypes returned as output.

instead write multiple `if` statements and then one if no conditions meet.

try like below:

```
numbervar counter;
shared stringvar Array FieldVal;
counter := count({?Fields}); 

if counter >= 5 then
(
if Not(NumericText(FieldVal[5]) and isdate(FieldVal[5])) then
FieldVal[5]
```

Else   if (NumericText(FieldVal[5]) 
then tonumber(FieldVal[5])
Else  if (isdate(FieldVal[5]) 
then CDate(FieldVal[5])
    );

Comment: I see how this might work, however, the formula returns the last data type defined in the formula.  So if I switch the order of the if statements, the last data type wins.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Because I cannot create a way for the code to exit a loop, the data takes the last data type in the code. i.e. if date is the last line, it tries to format date, or if number is the last line it tries to format as a number.

Comment: Didn't get you...can you show sample data by editing question... will try to solve

Comment: As of right now, the only thing I can think of is to overlay the fields and display them depending on their data type...  Pretty messy way to handle it.

Comment: There are currently 100 data fields in the report  To have to duplicate and maintain these will be very difficult, so trying to address in the code.

Comment: I am still having issues with making this work fully.  With all of the variables and overlapping fields I have had to include in the report, it has become extremely slow...

Comment: If you use so many fields it will be slow...so you need to write a formula in a single filed thats why I asked you to try my solution

Comment: Yes, that is what I did, and it only returns the data type of the last if statement in the formula.  If the last statement says FieldVal[5] then it returns a string no matter what the actual data type is which ends up being blank.  If I change it tonumber(FieldVal[5]), then it returns a number data type no matter what the actual data type is.  Hope I am making sense here.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the formula that you have written and also sample data so that I get some idea on where there was problem

Comment: I edited the question, you will see that there is a link, and that is a screen shot of the data returned.

Comment: @paul cabano updated my answer it should work now.. can you check

Comment: Hello Siva, that is the formula that I started with that gives me the data type issues.  It is maddening, isn't it???  Seems so simple.

Comment: That is correct, that formula is the original formula that I started with  that would not work because you cannot output different data types from the same "if, then, else" statement

Comment: You can overcome this by converting all datatypes to string...for example take date datatype so here logic would be first convert to date then again convert to string so final output would be everything is string and this formula works.. try and let me know

Comment: It works fine to convert everything to a string, but when we export it to excel for our end user, the data types have to be correct so they can use the spreadsheet for their business purposes.  I support 55,000 people and the vast majority of them do not have ANY excel skill.

Comment: Ok in this case why dont you try swith case in crystal reports

Comment: I receive the same error, "A date is required here".

Comment: In this case you nees to continue the approach that is working for you as you have constraint on how client use the reports

Comment: I appreciate all of your assistance.  The work around that I have causes the report to run for hours unfortunately because there are so many variables and formulas that have to be filled.  I cannot believe that something like this would be so difficult, but it really is!  Thanks again Siva :-)

Comment: No problem SO is meant to help fellow programmers but one suggestion formulas doesn't make report to run for hours you need to work on performance of the report like using selection formulas parameters etc...